# Can a family of functions $F_{\lambda}$ experience a saddle-node bifurcation and also experience a period -doubling bifurcation?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Suppose $F_{C}=(x-C)^{2}$ is a family of functions. I found that at $C=-\frac{1}{4}$ there is a saddle-node bifurcation. So for $C<-\frac{1}{4}$ there are $0$ fixed points, $C=-\frac{1}{4}$ there is one fixed point and $C>-\frac{1}{4}$ there are two fixed points. Now I am trying to figure out if there is a $C-value$ for which a period-doubling bifurcation exists. My question is, if a family of functions can experience a saddle-node bifurcation, can it also experience a period -doubling bifurcation?

Comment: Yes, it can (logistic mapping, for example). But why don't you look for this bifurcation directly?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what makes a bifurcation a period-doubling bifurcation.

Comment: A necessary condition for fixed point $p$ of mapping $x \mapsto f(x, \alpha)$ to undergo a period doubling bifurcation at $\alpha = \alpha_0$ is $f(p, \alpha_0) = p$ and $f’(p, \alpha_0) = -1$. In this simple case you can just verify that near $\alpha = \alpha_0$ you have fixed point coexisting with two nearby points of period 2.